# How to find words from a wordlist in a HTML/JS code stored in .txt file through a python program?

Tags: python, encryption

Right, so I'm making a python program to find certain words that can be hidden in the source code of a webpage. So far when I run my program on a source code, this error crops up

```
a = f1.read()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 53198: character maps to <undefined>
```

Here is my python program:

```
with open("G:/EncredX/sourcecode.txt") as f1:
    a = f1.read()
    print(a)
if("word" in a):
    print("word")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurs if the file uses another encoding while open default encoding will be platform dependent. Use:

```
with open("G:/EncredX/sourcecode.txt", encoding="latin1") as f1:
```

or

```
with open("G:/EncredX/sourcecode.txt", encoding="utf8") as f1:
```